# CSS how to make table's column width less than the content?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to make one width of column in table to be less, than content with. Here's my code:

**html**:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col1">col1</th>
            <th class="col2">col2</th>
            <th class="col3">col3</th>
            <th class="col4">col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">aaaaaa</td>
            <td class="col2">aaaaaa</td>
            <td class="col3">aaaaaa</td>
            <td class="col4">aaaaaa</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**scss**:

```
.table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}

td:first-child, th:first-child {
    width: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As I understand setting `table-layout: fixed` should helped, but nothing is really changed. The first column's with still is not 10px.

How can I set width to a column then?

[image: table]

Comment: so you want same width for al `td`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz, No. I want first column to be 10px, and other to be as content width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give it a try with `max-width` instead.

*disclaimer: unsure if all browsers will take it*

```css
.table {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed; 
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}

td:first-child, th:first-child {
    max-width: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col1">col1</th>
            <th class="col2">col2</th>
            <th class="col3">col3</th>
            <th class="col4">col4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="col1">aaaaaa</td>
            <td class="col2">aaaaaa</td>
            <td class="col3">aaaaaa</td>
            <td class="col4">aaaaaa</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also when I added `width: 100%` to the table, code started to work